# react router: using a menu on all pages but the frontpage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a site with a menu on all my pages, and I changed the front page so that now, I don't want that menu on it anymore, but I still want it everywhere else. So I've been thinking about two ways of doing it :

1. the bad way: having the `<Menu />` on each component, instead of inside the routes
2. the not so great way: having the `<Menu />` component not show itself when route is "/"
3. the good way: somehow using react router dom, to have it on all routes except "/"

I can't figure out how to implement `3.`, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `location.pathname` from the `Route` to not render it if it matches a specific path.

```
const Menu = ({ location: { pathname } }) => {
  return pathname !== "/" && <div>MENU</div>;
};
```

or use `useLocation` hook from [`react-router-dom`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)

```
const Menu = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation();
  return pathname !== "/" && <div>MENU</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit intelligent-shadow-vkl46]

**NOTE:** Ensure the menu is *not* being rendered within a `Switch` as they return only the first matching path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `useLocation` from `react-router-dom`. Something like this:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navigation = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  if (location.pathname === '/') return null;
  return (
     <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active">Page1</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/page2" activeClassName="active">Page2</NavLink></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

const Routing = () => (
  <Router>
    <Navigation />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={MainApp} />
      <Route path="/page2" component={Page2App} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the menu on the Router Page and use a conditional render just like this:

```
window.location.pathname !== '/' &&
    <Menu />

... rest of the routing
```

Comment: ok, so basically, option 3 doesn't exist ? I think this is the best solution because, you can see directly on the routes, why it doesn't show. I think it's better than having this code in the menu component.